# Date Formatting Mess

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, date, format

I am trying to format a date field that underwent incorrect importation.  The result was that the date format became coded in a way i am unsure of.

Is there a simple way using the field calculator to batch process date formats?

In the meantime, I will try to create a unique ID in order to join the two tables.

Here is what it currently is:
[image]

This is the format I want it in:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I believe these dates come from Excel and represent days since Jan 1, 1900.

From the [Office Help](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATE-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349):

> Note: Excel stores dates as sequential serial numbers so that they can
>   be used in calculations. January 1, 1900 is serial number 1, and
>   January 1, 2008 is serial number 39448 because it is 39,447 days after
>   January 1, 1900. You will need to change the number format (Format
>   Cells) in order to display a proper date.

You could use [Field Calculator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm) with Python code to calculate the new date field:

Codeblock:

```
import datetime

def calc_date(field):
  return '{}'.format(datetime.date(1900, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(int( field )))
```

Expression:

```
calc_date( !IntDate! )
```

The `38184` will thus become `2004-07-18`

And here is a solution you can run outside of Field Calculator (from your Python IDE or ArcMap Python window):

```
import arcpy
import datetime
fc = r'C:\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\_fishnet'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,['IntDate','RealDate']) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        row[1] = '{}'.format(datetime.date(1900, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(int( row[0] )))
        cur.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: For the Field Calculator route, am I to create a new field (float style)? Or use the field calc. on the existing field which I want to re-format? When I do run the Field Calculator, am I replacing your **{}** with the range of rows? And **field** with the name of the intended field? I am still new at python script.

Comment: @Sebastian.D For the field calculator, create a new field of type 'Date'.  The {} part is part of the string formatting and no you do not change it.  Use the expression as it is written, just replace !IntDate! with your field name.